# Excel vlookup continued on other columns

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

[image: Picture of columns]

I cannot append these rows because the list would get too large. I have every city, village etc in this sheet and its UN code. I want to `Vlookup` on an another sheet and match the UN code to POD(name of a place). How can I `Match` several columns?

I have tired:

```
=INDEX((codes!$B$2:$B$51112) * (codes!$F$2:$F$27403) * (codes!$L$2:$L$33880);MATCH(0;(codes!$C$2:$C$5112=E4)*(codes!$G$2:$G$27403=E4)*(codes!$M$2:$M$33880=E4);FALSE))
```

But I get `#VALUE!` error

[image: Picture of place to vlookup]

Here I have managed to lookup some city UN codes because they were in the first two coumns with POD and UN code. But how do I get the rest of columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can partition a range using `INDEX` and array constants. You will also need to use `XLOOKUP` instead of `HLOOKUP` or `VLOOKUP`, because you need to do both.

```
=XLOOKUP("c",INDEX(A1:D2,,{1,3}),INDEX(A1:D2,,{2,4}))
```

Use one such array for the lookup value (all the rows, columns 1 and 3) and another for the return value (all the rows, columns 2 and 4).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Image of sheet]

I found it easier to just directly Vlookup from the sheet where I had these cities. And do lookups for each of the columns and than just unite the columns with strings. But for some reason I couldn't find UN codes for all of the cities. I just filled them manually